# What is google recommand method to import sqlite3 C++ in bazel project?

Tags: c++, sqlite, bazel

How to import sqlite3 C++ to bazel project? I find many sqlite3 encapsulation with bazel build of third_party project since sqlite3 does not support bazel officially, and they worked. How can I import sqlite3 or any other officially single-source-file project elegantly? Perhaps there are some google recommend docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google internally hold everything in their repo. You don't want to do this, because you don't want to maintain each of external dependencies on your own.

If you want to see how to use bazel with C++ I recommend an [envoy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/main/bazel/external) project, because it is open source thus the used idiom are more applicable to the general usage than google internal stuff

I would use some existing rule definition like [rockwotj/sqlite-bazel](https://github.com/rockwotj/sqlite-bazel).